# Can't retrieve images from storage in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I can't retrieve images from storage and I don't know why. I tried many ways but not working. I ran the following command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

I tried these but none of it worked :

```html
<img src="/storage/images/{{$slide->image}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">

<img src="{{asset('/storage/images/'.$slide->image)}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">

<img src="{{Storage::get('public/images/', $slide->image) }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
```

Comment: Can you check, where you upload the image. Is your image saved in this folder `storage/app/public/image.jpg`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`php artisan storage:link` creates a [symbolic link](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolische_Verkn%C3%BCpfung) from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`.

So you have to call `public/storage/images/` to access the image.

So in your blade you need to link the source to something like this:

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/app/images/'.$slide->image) }}"></img>
```

Comment: @Developer that has nothing to do with your question that is currently only a warning from chrome. You should read the docs. Maybe you forgot to add the csrf token.

Comment: I found what is the problem . I'm using ubuntu OS, Homestead environment, so the solution is to : remove the storage shortcut from public, run vagrant ssh then navigate to that project and run php artisan storage:link

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = url('storage/app/public/images/') . $variableName;
<img src='.$url.'>
```